# DateTime with date('Y') function

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to check if an event from this year is in the future or over.
So i buildt this and it works.

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-04-07');
$now  = new DateTime();

if($date > $now) {
    echo 'future';
} else {
    echo 'past';
}
```

But i don't want to change every year the "`2016`" to keep it working in the next year.
Is it possible to add for the `2016` the actually year?

Something like:

```
$date = new DateTime('".date('Y')."-04-07');
```

Thanks

Comment: You're actually passing the `date('Y')` as a string and not a function, because it's inside the quotes. `new DateTime(date('Y')."-04-07")` should be what you're looking for.

Comment: What is the event date? Where does that come from? Surely that must be a variable you get from somewhere, so that wont always have 2016 in it?? will it???

Comment: The *"Try this"* clan have posted something for you below; "try that".

Comment: @Qirel Personally, I think your comment holds (a lot) more water than the "try this clan" answers below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Aye, "*teach a man to fish..*" ;-)

Comment: *Exactly!* - @Qirel ;-) It's easy to go to the local fish market and simply pick "one" up. But out in the country lakes and rivers, those are rather hard to find; if non-existant too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$date = new DateTime(date('Y').'-04-07');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
$date = date("Y")."-04-07";
$date = new DateTime($date);
```

Or simply:

`$date = new DateTime(date("Y")."-04-07");`